# Python HTTP server not responding on POST and GET requests

Tags: python, http

I need to create an HTTP sever, that handle Get and Post request with an HTML page.
I want the name and last name to be sent in Post request to the server, and then to be displayed on the screen with Get request.
I created an HTML page, and created an HTTP server.
I am not sure however, how to make everything connect. I am keep on getting errors. 
The error I'm currently receiving:
Error code: 501

Message: Unsupported method ('POST').

Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED - Server does not support this operation.

Seems like the issue is that the server doesn't support Post request, but I am not sure how to make it support the request.

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: use framework `Flask`, `Django`, `Bottle` or similar to create web page. It will be easier.

Comment: this code doesn't support `POST` because every `POST` can send different data and servers will not  know what to do with this data. You have to write own class `Handler` with method `post`. It should be in documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create own `Handler` with method `do_POST`

```
import http.server
import socketserver

class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        print("POST received")

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("Hello World".encode('utf-8'))


PORT = 8080
Handler = MyHandler#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

I tested it with

```
import requests

r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080')
print(r.text)
```

I don't know how to get values sent in POST request - I never had to use it.

It is easier to do it with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/), [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/), etc.

---

**EDIT:** The same with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/). It also shows how to get values sent and use in response.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form['name'], request.form['last_name'])
        return "Hello " + request.form['last_name']
    return "Hello World"

app.run(port=8080)
```

Tested with

```
import requests

form = {'name': 'James', 'last_name': 'Bond'}

r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080', data=form)

print(r.text) # Hello Bond
```